# For an Angular app, why do hotkeys not work in Chrome until the user interacts with the page

Tags: angular, google-chrome, hotkeys

Using Angular I have various HostListeners listening for keydown:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
keyEvent(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log(evt)
}
```

I can see in the console logs that this is firing. But it won't fire until I interact with the page in some way (e.g. by clicking on it first) and after that it works great.

Is this expected behaviour? If not, how do I fix it such that the hotkeys work without the user first interacting with the page?

NB: On https://duckduckgo.com the arrows keys seem to work without interacting with the page - maybe this is just something to do with TabIndex?

NB: This problem exists in Chrome. I haven't tested in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because they have an element (the input) auto focused. On your application call .focus() on the body.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(document.body)
    document.body.focus()
  }

Comment: I tried the above code, it logs the document body as <body>...</body> but calling document.body.focus() did not fix the issue - thanks for the idea though

Comment: I've added my own answer but am going to accept this one since it helped me on the way

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a crazy hacky fix for this after I noticed that the hotkeys worked after pressing the Tab key (which selected a button).

So I just added a useless button to the page and hid it off screen and set the focus on that. Now the hotkeys work on page load.

Code as follows:

TS:

```
@ViewChild('setFocusOnMeToMakeHotkeysWorkOnPageLoad') setFocusOnMeToMakeHotkeysWorkOnPageLoad: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>

ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setFocusOnMeToMakeHotkeysWorkOnPageLoad.nativeElement.focus()
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<button #setFocusOnMeToMakeHotkeysWorkOnPageLoad id="set-focus-on-me-to-make-hotkeys-work-on-page-load"></button>
```

CSS:

```
#set-focus-on-me-to-make-hotkeys-work-on-page-load {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: -1000px;
}
```